# how to rotate object around world axis with webgl and glMatrix

Tags: javascript, rotation, webgl

I'm trying to rotate a cube so that dragging down always rotates the object around the world X axis, and dragging to the side always rotates the object around the world Y axis no matter the rotation of the object. I've seen this example which achieves the exact behavior I am looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/n6u6asza/

```
$(renderer.domElement).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
})
.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    var deltaMove = {
        x: e.offsetX-previousMousePosition.x,
        y: e.offsetY-previousMousePosition.y
    };

    if(isDragging) {

        var deltaRotationQuaternion = new three.Quaternion()
            .setFromEuler(new three.Euler(
                toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                0,
                'XYZ'
            ));

        cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
    }

    previousMousePosition = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
    };
});
```

Here's my jsFiddle code that I'm having trouble with:
http://jsfiddle.net/9sqvp52u/

```
var eye = vec3.fromValues(0, 5, radius * 1.5);
var target = vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 0);
var up = vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0);
var vm = mat4.create();
var pvm = mat4.create();
var q = quat.create();
var rot = mat4.create();

// 1. perspective matrix
mat4.perspective(pvm, fovy, aspect, near, far);
// 2. view matrix
mat4.lookAt(vm, eye, target, up);
mat4.multiply(pvm, pvm, vm);
// 3. model matrix
var degY = radToDeg(dY);
var degX = radToDeg(dX);
quat.fromEuler(q, degY, degX, 0);
mat4.fromQuat(rot, q);
mat4.multiply(pvm, pvm, rot);
```

I saw this stackoverflow answer: [OpenGL transforming objects with multiple rotations of Different axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091505/opengl-transforming-objects-with-multiple-rotations-of-different-axis)

But I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I think I'm still multiplying the rotation matrix to the left side of the object matrix in my code, but the object is always just rotating around its local axis.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have to apply the new rotation to the model after the previous rotations have been applied, but before the view and the projection matrix.

If you have a `mat4 model` where all the previous rotation operations have been collected and you want to apply a new rotation `newrot` to the model, then the final transformation is calculated as follows:

```
projection * view * newrot * model
```

To solve your issue you have to create a model matrix:

```
var model = mat4.create();
var newrot = mat4.create();
```

Aplly the new rotation matrix to the model matrix and calculate a final matrix:

```
var degY = radToDeg(dY);
var degX = radToDeg(dX);
quat.fromEuler(q, degY, degX, 0);
mat4.fromQuat(newrot, q);
mat4.multiply(model, newrot, model);

var final = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(final, pvm, model);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_matrix, false, final);
```

See the example where I've applied the changes to your original code:

```js
function main(images) {

document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('canvas'));

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = 'canvas';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
if (!gl) {
    return;
}

var AMORTIZATION = 0.95;
var drag = false;
var old_x, old_y;
var dX = 0, dY = 0;
var mouseDown = function (e) {
    drag = true;
    old_x = e.pageX;
    old_y = e.pageY;

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

var mouseUp = function (e) {
    drag = false;
};

var mouseMove = function (e) {
    if (!drag) return false;
    dX = (e.pageX - old_x) * 2 * Math.PI / canvas.width;
    dY = (e.pageY - old_y) * 2 * Math.PI / canvas.height;
    THETA += dX;
    PHI += dY;
    old_x = e.pageX, old_y = e.pageY;

    e.preventDefault();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseUp, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);


const vertexShaderSource = document.getElementById('2d-vertex-shader').text;
const fragmentShaderSource = document.getElementById('2d-fragment-shader').text;

const program = gl.createProgram();

const vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vShader, vertexShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(vShader);

const fShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fShader, fragmentShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(fShader);

gl.attachShader(program, vShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

gl.useProgram(program);

var color = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'color');
var position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
var u_matrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_matrix');
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position);

var multiplier = 1;
const width = canvas.clientWidth * multiplier | 0;
const height = canvas.clientHeight * multiplier | 0;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

var vertexData = [
    // x,    y,    z
    // front face (z: +1)
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, // top right
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, // top left
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, // bottom left
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, // bottom right
    // right face (x: +1)
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // top right
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, // top left
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, // bottom left
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // bottom right
    // top face (y: +1)
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // top right
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // top left
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, // bottom left
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, // bottom right
    // left face (x: -1)
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, // top right
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // top left
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // bottom left
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, // bottom right
    // bottom face (y: -1)
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, // top right
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, // top left
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // bottom left
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // bottom right
    // back face (z: -1)
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // top right
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // top left
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // bottom left
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0  // bottom right
];

var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 0.5, 0.5,
        1.0, 0.5, 0.5,
        1.0, 0.5, 0.5,
        1.0, 0.5, 0.5,

        1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
);

var vertexIndexData = [
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,    // Front face
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,    // Back face
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11,  // Top face
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // Right face
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23  // Left face
];
var vertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(vertexIndexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


var fovy = degToRad(40);
var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
var near = 0.1;
var far = -10;
var radius = 10;
var up = [0, 1, 0];
var time_old = 0;
var THETA = 0;
var PHI = 0;

var eye = vec3.fromValues(0, 5, radius * 1.5);
var target = vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 0);
var up = vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0);
var vm = mat4.create();
var pvm = mat4.create();
var q = quat.create();
var newrot = mat4.create();
var model = mat4.create();

// 1. perspective matrix
mat4.perspective(pvm, fovy, aspect, near, far);
// 2. view matrix
mat4.lookAt(vm, eye, target, up);
mat4.multiply(pvm, pvm, vm);

requestAnimationFrame(render);

// Draw the scene.
function render(time) {
    // var dt = time - time_old;
    if (!drag) {
        dX *= AMORTIZATION;
        dY *= AMORTIZATION;
    }

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.clearColor(198/255, 222/255, 183/255, 1);

    var degY = radToDeg(dY);
    var degX = radToDeg(dX);
    quat.fromEuler(q, degY, degX, 0);
    mat4.fromQuat(newrot, q);
    mat4.multiply(model, newrot, model);

    var final = mat4.create();
    mat4.multiply(final, pvm, model);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_matrix, false, final);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndexBuffer);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
}

function radToDeg(r) {
return r * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function degToRad(d) {
return d * Math.PI / 180;
}

main();
```

```css
#canvas { width: 900px; height: 600px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="uiContainer">
    <div id="ui">
        <div id="cameraAngle"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="notjs">
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec4 color;

    uniform mat4 u_matrix;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
        vColor = color;
    }
</script>
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="notjs">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.7.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```